# iOS - how to scale to mobile device given only a url

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, url

i have a weblink from an external site. All i have is this link, it looks something like this:  www.mysite.com?locale=french

the site is not mobile yet so it does not scale to mobile device.  Remember this site is not mine and all i have is a link.  How can i add something to the link so that it scales on a mobile device.  For example could i add javascript to the link itself (which might not be safe to avoid injection etc).Please advise and the link is being executed from a iphone app on iOS 8.

UPDATE: Since im invoking the url from withint ios is there a command i can use that while its opening to run javascript or inject javascript ?

Comment: You cannot magically change a site without changing the site.

Comment: Jeez, wouldn't it be nice to just press a button and things resized?

Comment: ok what about with javascript ? there is a way to enter javascript from the url right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to just change a website by just adding something to the link. You have to design the website for mobile compatibility. This requires alot of different techniques, sometimes teams, sometimes more money. The entire website has to be reprogrammed to be dynamic with any device size.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like t9space which will make websites friendly to mobile. t9space is currently not available. but you can google alternatives for that.

http://appcrawlr.com/android/t9space